# change ajax form select box select otomatis

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html-table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IhcO.png)

Please help me..
auto fill works for the first field

but I have problem in the second row and next row too. When I change the select option on second row, the previous field changed (not same row as what I have changed):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDGmh.png)

```
var Nomor = $('#TabelTambahBarang tbody tr').length + 1;
var Baris = "<tr>";
Baris += "<td class='txt-center'>"+Nomor+"</td>"var Baris = "<tr>";
Baris += "<td class='txt-center'>"+Nomor+"</td>";
Baris += "<td>";
Baris += "<select placeholder='Items Name' class='form-control input-sm select2' name='nama_barang[]' id='nama_barang" + Nomor + "' data-Nomor='" + Nomor + "'>";
Baris += "<option disabled value='' name='nama_barang[]' id='nama_barang" + Nomor + "' data-Nomor='" + Nomor + "' selected hidden>-- Silahkan Nama Barang --</option>";;enter code here   
<?php
  if (!empty($dataBarang)) {
    foreach ($dataBarang as $k) { ?>
        Baris += "<option value='<?php echo $k->nama_barang; ?>'><?php echo $k->nama_barang; ?></option>";
    <?php }
}
?>
Baris += "</select>";
Baris += "</td>";
Baris += "<td class='txt-center'><input class='form-control input-sm' id='harga_barang' placeholder='Harga Barang'  name='harga_barang'/></td>";
Baris += "<td align='center'><a id='HapusBaris'>Delete</a></td>";
Baris += "</tr>";

$('#TabelTambahBarang tbody').append(Baris);
Nomor++;
select2();
}
$(document).on("change", ".select2", function(e) {
    var select = $(this);
    var nama_barang = select.val();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url  : "<?php echo base_url('get_barang')?>",
        dataType : "json",
        data : {nama_barang: nama_barang},
        cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                $.each(data,function(harga_barang){ 
                    $('[id="harga_barang"]').val(data.harga_barang);

                });   
            }
        });
    });
function select2(){
$('.select2').select2()
}
```

Controller

```
public function get_barang(){
  $nama_barang    = $this->input->post('nama_barang');
  $data           = $this->m_testing->get_barang($nama_barang);
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_barang($nama_barang){
    $hsl = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabel_barang WHERE nama_barang='$nama_barang'");
    if($hsl->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($hsl->result() as $data) {
            $hasil=array(
                'nama_barang'   => $data->nama_barang,
                'harga_barang'  => $data->harga_barang,
                );
        }
    }
    return $hasil;
}
```

Comment: because you have given same `id` for all row instead use `class="harga_barang"` and do like this `select.closest('tr').find('input.harga_barang').val(data.harga_barang);`

Comment: I put this code where brother `select.closest('tr').find('input.harga_barang').val(data.harga_barang);`

Comment: Instead of `$('[id="harga_barang"]').val(data.harga_barang);` line try that code .

Comment: I've done that, but it's not working

Comment: did you add class to your input-box?  Working fiddle with demo datas--> https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/5hdg24Ly/

Comment: yes it worked. You are wonderful, thank you so much for the help you have provided.